# How Do I Remove This Error in Firebase: "This domain is already in use."?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to add a custom domain to an existing project but keep getting the error that "this domain is already in use." I'm not using this domain anywhere else in any other project.

There is only 1 other forum post (http://grokbase.com/t/gg/firebase-talk/165r5n78nq/firebase-domain-is-already-in-use) about this error but following the step provided leads to zero results.

Comment: There's not a lot we can tell here on Stack Overflow with the information you provided. It's probably best to reach out to Firebase support to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: What other information would you need to better answer this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to anything the average developer can help with.

Comment: Have you used other subdomains of the same domain with other Firebase projects? It doesn't sound like it, but possibly you meant "I'm not using this SUBdomain anywhere else". That's what caused this error message for me - you can't have more than one Firebase project on different subdomains, much to my surprise and annoyance. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/nWv2i2M-KhM/763FgxWhFwAJ

Comment: Also, some people have had trouble when they had previously used the same domain for other projects, even if they had deleted those projects. I'm not sure if the previous projects were necessarily on Firebase, or if they might have used other Google services.

Comment: The domain _was_ used in another (deleted) project. I thought that once a project was deleted from my account that it would remove the connection to the domain used. That's not the case. You must wait 7 days for the project to be completely removed, then you can use that domain again. This ticket can be closed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are getting that error it means that you're already using the domain in a project.  You probably deleted the project but did not disconnect the domain before it was shut down. In this case, you can either wait for 10 days from when you deleted the project for it to be removed or, 
you can restore the project by going to the [Firebase IAM & Admin console](https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/projects) click on projects pending shutdown.

Then proceed to disconnect the domain from the project like you normally would. Now you can use that domain again with no problem.

Comment: Restoring the project doesn't seem to add it back to Firebase, so there does not appear to be a way to remove the domain from the restore project.

Comment: The project was added to Firebase in almost 30 seconds then I can remove the dns, it works for me. Thanks buddy

Comment: Beware: Restored projects are always problematic.

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project and click on 'Projects Pending Deletion" click Restore.  Then go to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/YOUR-PROJ-ID/hosting/main and delete the domain connection(s).

That should free the domain up for a new SSL cert.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `appname.page.link` make **appname** uniqe
[image: dynamic link firebase]

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: this domain name must be unique over existing domains in xxx.page.link  ie. email must be unique 'uniquename@gmail.com' for every one
 https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/