# Disconnected domain from blogger and Firebase Hosting still showing "Domain already in use"

Tags: firebase, blogger, firebase-hosting

A subdomain is linked to my blog on [blogger](https://www.blogger.com). When i tried to use the domain (not subdomain) to firebase hosting , it shows "Domain already in use".

So, i disconnected subdomain from blogger, but still not able to use domain or any subdomain within the same domain in firebase hosting. Still showing"Domain already in use".

Need to use domain and its subdomains with Firebase Hosting.

Followed posts:

- [How Do I Remove This Error in Firebase: "This domain is already in use."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951909/how-do-i-remove-this-error-in-firebase-this-domain-is-already-in-use)
- [Firebase Domain already in use](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/firebase-talk/165r5n78nq/firebase-domain-is-already-in-use)

These solutions are not working in this case.

Comment: Please reach out to Firebase support for help with something like this.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Already filed a ticket at firebase support. waiting for response.

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes takes 12 to 24 hours to reset the domain.  Make sure you add the name servers to your domain

Comment: i was already using domain with different host. So name server is not the issue. Its issue with domain acceptence from firebase hosting, which is showing domain in use